# How to load a template based on the first segment (and ignoring the second)

Tags: entries, sections, routing

So I have my dinnermenu at `example.com/dinnermenu` but I want to show specific content for the next week if someone asks for it via `example.com/dinnermenu/nextWeek` but it should still use the entry data from dinnermenu ...

how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to go about this depending on how you have your sections and templates set up, and where you are getting your content from for both 'dinnermenu' and 'nextweek'.

**Using routes**

If you just want 'dinnermenu/nextweek' requests to be directed to the 'dinnermenu' template, then one option would be to set up a [dynamic route](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes) with a '*' token as the last segment (i.e. `dinnermenu/*`). This would route `example.com/dinnermenu/any-uri-segment` to your 'dinnermenu' template ('dinnermenu.html' or 'dinnermenu/index.html' or whatever you called it).

In the dinnermenu template you can then test for the uri segment and display custom 'nextweek' content, in addition to (or instead of) your dinner menu content.

```
{% if craft.request.segments(2) == 'nextweek' %}
    // display content for next week
{% endif %}
```

See [craft.request](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request) for more info.

**Using a structure**

For more dynamic nav you could also use a 'structure' (with 2 levels). In the template you can then test for the level and include the parent content as needed.

```
{% switch entry.level %}
    {% case "1" %}
        {% set dinnermenu = entry %}
    {% case "2" %}
        {% set dinnermenu = entry.parent %}
{% endswitch %}

{{ entry.intro }}     // dinnermenu's or nextweek's 'intro' field
{{ dinnermenu.body }} // with dinnermenu's body field
```

**Using ElementCriteriaModel**

If on the other hand, you want to pull your 'dinnermenu' entry into your 'nextweek' template (no matter where it is), then you can use an `EntryCriteriaModel` to retrieve and display the 'dinnermenu' entry.

```
{% set dinnermenu = craft.entries.slug('dinnermenu').first %}
{{ dinnermenu.body }}
etc.
```

You could also just include the whole 'dinnermenu' template in the 'nextweek' template.

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.slug('dinnermenu').first %}
{% include 'dinnermenu.html' %}
```

Lot of options.

Comment: I tried the route method - but then it can't access my data in the entry tag somehow

Comment: Just set it manually. `{% set entry = craft.entries.section('mysection').slug('dinnermenu').first %}`

Comment: perfect :) that was what I needed

Comment: Great! maybe mark this as correct then